# Rename local user group on Debian/Ubuntu with Puppet

Tags: ubuntu, debian, puppet

Via Samba with idmap_rid, users and groups from LDAP are available on the Ubuntu systems. However, a collision occurs for the user group name `staff` with Debian/Ubuntu's own local user group `staff` (GID: 50).

Therefore I would like to rename the local user group `staff` to `debian-staff`.

I tried to implement this via Puppet, which unfortunately did not work. Puppet seems to always try a `groupadd` instead of `groupmod`, although the local GID 50 already exists.

```
group { 'debian-staff':
    ensure => present,
    gid => 50,
    forcelocal => true,
}
```

> Error: Could not create group debian-staff: Execution of '/usr/sbin/groupadd -g 50 debian-staff' returned 4: groupadd: GID '50' already exists

How can I rename a local user group with Puppet?

Comment: The group type verifies existence on the name of the group and not the gid, and therefore you could not rename (update) a group like this. It would need to be a delete/create operation.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I rename a local user group with Puppet?

You cannot do that with the built in `Group` resource type, because the group name is the *namevar* of that type.  That is, its unique identifier.  A `Group` with a different name is necessarily a different group.

In principle, you could remove the `Group` and then add a different one, but that might still present an issue both initially (if the system attempts to manage the LDAP group instead of the local one) and afterward (because even if the LDAP group was not selected for modification before, it stands a good chance of being selected on subsequent runs, after the conflict is resolved).  Additionally, that might lose information you care about, such as users who have the local `staff` group as a secondary group.

One quick and dirty way to genuinely change a group name would be something like this:

```
  exec { 'rename local "staff" group':
    command => [
      '/bin/bash',
      '-c',
      'for f in /etc/{shadow,gshadow}; do /bin/sed --in-place s/^staff:/debian-staff:/ "$f"; done'
      ],
    onlyif  => 'grep -q ^staff: /etc/group'
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The most useful way I have found to rename groups via Puppet is:

```
exec { 'rename local group staff to debian-staff':
    command => 'groupmod --new-name debian-staff staff',
    path    => '/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin',
    onlyif  => "grep /etc/group -e '^staff:x:50:'",
}
```

The `groupmod` command is used to rename, but only if the `staff` group with ID `50` is found in `/etc/group`.

---

The [`group` resource type](https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/8/types/group.html) can only identify groups by name, not by number, and does not provide for renaming.